# Disable PDF printing in Firefox by web developer

Tags: pdf, firefox

I am developing a web page to show PDF (in .NET platform).  The PDF is inside a iframe.  One of the requirement is NOT allow client to print the PDF.  I have already made the PDF to be password protected (with pdfsharp).  I further hide the toolbar by setting toolbar=0.  In Chrome & IE, this works fine.  But for Firefox, the story is totally different.

In Firefox, the toolbar will be shown even append #toolbar=0 in the src link.  Further, the password protected pdf can be printed by simply clicking the icon in the toolbar.

Can anyone suggest some ways to disable pdf printing in firefox.

Note: I need to show the PDF in the webpage.  So, download the PDF is not a option.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to control the toolbar or the ability to print (not all PDF viewers respect the permissions set by the password) if you rely on the native browser or OS level PDF viewer by using an iFrame. Different browsers will interpret those settings differently. Even different applications within the same browser will yield different results (Chrome vs Dropbox in Chrome)

You'll need to display the PDF using something like PDF.js or another such library if you want any kind of consistency in appearance and behavior.